# Deep node_module paths. Any solutions?

Tags: node.js, npm

Sometimes it's very annoying. (255 character limit)
Maybe someone know good solution for it?
How to do it shorter? Or not so deep?

> L:\ls\libsass\node_modules\gulp-w3cjs\node_modules\w3cjs\node_modules\superagent-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\node_modules\pac-proxy-agent\node_modules\pac-resolver\node_modules\degenerator\node_modules\escodegen\node_modules\source-map\n
>   ode_modules\amdefine

node_modules ... node_modules ... grrr

SOLUTION:

It will be solved in npm 3.0.0 version.

> Your dependencies will now be installed maximally flat. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder with no nesting.

Right now you can try beta "npm install -g npm@3.0-latest"

[link](http://dailyjs.com/2015/06/26/npm-3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally

cmd
npm install npm -g

Answer (score 1):

> That's an issue with Windows Explorer limitation, not something npm
>   can control. npm (and node) use filesystem methods that do not have
>   this limitation; if you are using other software (such as Windows
>   Explorer) that does not support long file names, the bugs need to be
>   fixed there, and not in npm. [source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4054)

Also notice this:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3697#issuecomment-114665926